# How to convert days to datetime where time origin is 1-JAN-0000 00:00:00?

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-xarray, python-datetime

I have a netCDF dataset which includes coordinates of 'time' and 'depth'. The time coordinate has data stored in the format of days, where origin time is 'JAN1-0000 00:00:00' (Image for the dataset is attached below).
I want to know how to convert those days to correct datetime format ?[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "correct format"? A datetime data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `719528` days between year 0 and epoch (1970-01-01).

You can subtract those days and use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with days as unit:

```
time = np.array([731957.5, 731958.5])

out = pd.to_datetime(time-719528, unit='d')
```

output: `DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-12 12:00:00', '2004-01-13 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)`